# Set variables in feature file in protractor-cucumber frame work

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor 5.2.2 with cucumber 3.2.1 and while i am set a variable as "browser.params.UserName" , it is taking as a actual value instead as a variable.How can i specify it as a variable in feature file.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's no way, that's Cucumber Feature file work mechanism.  But we can did some trick (I'm not sure it's your wanted)

```
// feature file   
Given user login with account "UserName"

// step defintion    
Given(/^user login with account "(.*)"$/, function(accountKey){ 
   var account = browser.params[accountKey]
})
```

Comment: Yes..above trick work for me.I have passed an external file by specifying params: require(filepath) in config file.So can we add more than one external file paths?when i have try to add multiple file path, got error.Thanks in advance

Comment: please give examples for external files and tell us what your want to archive?  do you specify the external file path in command line?